# Check if class is a subclass of specific generic

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
public class HtSecurePage : UserControl, IDisposable
{

}

public class HtSecureInstancePage<T1> : HtSecurePage
{

}

public partial class NormalPage : HtSecurePage
{

}

public partial class InstancePage : HtSecureInstancePage<ZlsManager>
{

}
```

To check if `NormalPage` is a `subClass` of `HtSecurePage` I use the following pattern.

```
if (typeof(NormalPage).BaseType == typeof(HtSecurePage))
{

}
```

If I use this pattern against `InstancePage`, it is not working.

```
if (typeof(InstancePage).BaseType == typeof(HtSecureInstancePage<>))
{

}
```

---

I need to know if a `Type` is a direct `subClass` of `HtSecurePage` or `HtSecureInstancePage<>`. (It's **important** not to check against `HtSecureInstancePage<ZlsManager>`!) The `Type T1` is unknown.

Comment: I dont get this. If you replace `NormalPage` with `InstancePage` the result will be `false` not `true`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I had a logic mistake in the question. I made an edit. I have 500  `Types` and want to sort them. There are also `Types` which aren't inherited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below function check your class' sub-class the same type supplied class. If types is generic, check operation is executed over generic type definition.

#### Method usage

```
bool isInherited = CheckIsDirectlyInherited(typeof(TestAbstract), new[] {typeof(SecondLevelAbstractClass), typeof(FirstLevelAbstract)});
```

#### Method

```
bool CheckIsDirectlyInherited(Type obj, Type[] baseTypes)
{
    if (obj.BaseType == null)
        return false;

    var objGenericDefinition = obj.BaseType;
    if (objGenericDefinition.IsGenericType)
    {
        objGenericDefinition = objGenericDefinition.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    }

    foreach (Type baseType in baseTypes)
    {
        var baseTypeDefinition = baseType;
        if (baseTypeDefinition.IsGenericType)
            baseTypeDefinition = baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

        if (objGenericDefinition == baseTypeDefinition)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly I was looking for!!

Comment: I am happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

> is a direct subClass of HtSecurePage

I think you already know how to do it

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(HtSecureInstancePage<ZlsManager>).BaseType == typeof(HtSecurePage));
```

> is a direct subClass of HtSecureInstancePage<>

To check it you can use something like this:

```
static bool IsDirectSubclassOfRawGeneric(Type parent, Type toCheck)
{
    return toCheck.BaseType.IsGenericType && parent == toCheck.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
}
...
Console.WriteLine(IsDirectSubclassOfRawGeneric(typeof(HtSecureInstancePage<>), typeof(InstancePage)));
```